# Record Video on Android without showing the video on screen

Tags: android, video-capture

I have been unsuccessfully trying to record video.  My code compiles, but crashes when I try to run it.  Does anyone know how I can record without changing the view on the screen?  Thanks.

```
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    recorder.setMaxDuration(15000); // 15 seconds
    recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/xxxxx.mp4");
    recorder.start();
```

Comment: Might help if you provided the exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

you need to specify a valid Surface: `recorder.setPreviewDisplay().` Then you can call `recorder.prepare()`, and only then `recorder.start()`.

The need for a valid surface is quit annoying, there's a thread about removing it here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9570

That would for example allow background app to record video.